# Linking zlib in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, zlib, lnk2019

I have a C++ program that compiled and ran fine on Linux that I am now trying to compile on a Windows machine in Visual Studio. The main problem I'm facing is the following error message:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _gzread referenced in function

I have downloaded the zlib library and attempted to link it to my project, but apparently unsuccessfully. I'd appreciate clear instructions on how to link this to my project. The less you assume in your instructions, the better, as I'm relatively new to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. Even though I'm working on a 64-bit machine, VS was compiling in 32-bit mode. I just used the 32-bit version of zlibwapi instead of the 64-bit version and it worked.